# Different user profile's tabs when user is or isn't logged in

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

When I'm logged in and access [my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/189165/trejder) page, I'm redirected to "**Activity**" tab by default:

[image]

When I open my profile page, when I'm logged-off, I see "**Profile**" tab by default:

[image]

Is this a bug or by-design?

Comment: I think you're on a different tab in the first screenshot - the Activity tab.

Comment: Yeah, looks like we're defaulting you to Activity when you view your own profile.

Comment: Actually, it seems, that you're defaulting to different tabs, when user is or isn't logged-in. Let me check this out and eventually reformulate the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design –  a link to another user profile takes you to his "Profile" tab, while link to the profile of currently logged in user takes you to "Activity" tab, as it is more likely that you are interested in your activity.

When you are not logged in, system doesn't know this profile is yours, so it takes you to the "Profile" tab.